# Velocity template localization

Tags: java, localization, velocity

I'm working on a task that's using Velocity to generate an email from a template.  One of my requirements is that the email message be localized, based on a `Locale` submitted by the user.  I've got this working for the most part, using Velocity's `ResourceTool` to pull in a `MessageBundle`.  The other requirement is that I can only have one template - I don't want one template per language or locale because this is difficult to maintain if changes are needed.

As a part of a `MessageBundle`, I can have what's referred to as "compound messages", which are messages that have variables that are replaced when the message is evaluated.  For example:

```
dear.name=Dear {0}:
```

My question is this: how do I get Velocity to replace the `{0}` value with a name that I pass in?

It's not acceptable to simply modify my Velocity template so that I simply replace the name at the template level - in some languages, the greeting word "Dear" comes after the name, so this would yield an incorrect output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer: in my velocity template, I can use the Velocity directive:

```
#evaluate(${msg.dear.name})
```

And in my message bundle, my message looks like:

```
dear.name=Dear $name
```

If I set the name in the Velocity context, it gets replaced as I expect.